# How can I access OS X display settings programatically?

Tags: macos, settings, accessibility

OS X has some display settings like "Increase contrast" and "Reduce transparency" within the Accessibility System Preferences. How can I read those programatically from my sandboxed app to adopt them in my own custom controls?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just check NSWorkspace.shared().accessibilityDisplayShouldIncreaseContrast and NSWorkspace.shared().accessibilityDisplayShouldReduceTransparency